# cmake find_library() not finding library specified by PATHS

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I have a `find_library()` statement that matches below (this is based on the [amazon kinesis project](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c)):

`find_library(SRTP_LIBRARIES NAMES srtp2 REQUIRED PATHS ${OPEN_SRC_INSTALL_LIB_PREFIX})`

The `OPEN_SRC_INSTALL_LIB_PREFIX` correctly points to the location where this library is located. I can observe this directly. However, this `find_library()` call fails and I am confused as to why it would do so.

I thought that maybe cmake is searching through other paths first and ignoring my specified path, so I also tried it with the `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` flag, as that should limit the search to *only* be in the paths specified:

`find_library(SRTP_LIBRARIES NAMES srtp2 REQUIRED PATHS ${OPEN_SRC_INSTALL_LIB_PREFIX} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)`

... still no luck.

Any ideas why this would not work? I've verified the `OPEN_SRC_INSTALL_LIB_PREFIX` is the valid directory of the library via `message()` prints.

Note that this is **cross compiling**, although I don't see why that would change the behavior of `find_library()` unless I'm missing something from [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/find_library.html)

Comment: Add `--debug-find` option to `cmake` and examine output corresponded to your `find_library` call. It should print which paths are actually searched and which paths are ignored.

Comment: Good tip @Tsyvarev, I now see that it is not in fact using the PATHS I pass in at all... any ideas on why this would be the case? is there some sort of caching going on? it appears to be using the SYSROOT path instead, and then uses no paths when I specify NO_DEFAULT_PATH (even though PATHS is defined and valid)

Comment: This seems very relevant: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20772

Comment: ```The CMAKE_SYSROOT variable can also be used to specify exactly one directory to use as a prefix. Setting CMAKE_SYSROOT also has other effects. See the documentation for that variable for more.```

Comment: I'm guessing this is what is borking me up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First want to note I'm on `cmake` 17.5.

Ok, so the documentation is a bit confusing, but it seems that the `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` would only use the paths specified by the `PATHS` argument and none of the other cache variables, but that *doesn't* seem to be the case if `CMAKE_SYSROOT` is set.

Using the `NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` is what actually causes `find_library()` to ignore the cached paths.